# Error:Cannot use object of type QueryResult as array - PHP Tool Kit

Tags: apex, integration, php

1) I have an PHP Form that post all the gathered information(I.e when the user enters the details and clicks on submit )it will post to the to the Php file for processing

**Error:
Cannot use object of type QueryResult as array**

Code Snippet(Php file):

```
$query = "SELECT Id,Name FROM Position__c WHERE  Name='".$_POST['position']."' LIMIT 1";
 $response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);
$queryResult = new QueryResult($response);
echo $queryResult['ID'][0];
var_dump($queryResult->records[0]->Id[0]);

    $fields = array (
    'First_Name__c' => $_POST['firstname'],
    'Last_Name__c' => $_POST['lastname'],
    'Position__c'=>$queryResult->records[0]->Id[0], );
    $sObject = new SObject();
     $sObject->fields = $fields;
 $sObject->type = 'Candidate__c';
echo "**** Creating the following:\r\n";
$createResponse = $mySforceConnection->create(array($sObject));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QueryResult is not an array. Use the records array member of the query result to learn about records returned. The QueryResult itself includes details about the total number of records returned and a QueryLocator if queryMore is required to obtain more results. I'm specifically referring to the fourth line of code in your snippet.

Comment: I am getting the                                                                                                **Error : object(QueryResult)#5 (6) { ["queryLocator"]=> NULL ["done"]=> bool(true) ["records"]=> array(0) { } ["size"]=> int(0) ["pointer"]=> int(0) ["sf":"QueryResult":private]=> bool(false) }**

Comment: I am not getting any value from the query Result.

Comment: @PraveenKumar If you don't have a match, it would return nothing. I've used the PHP toolkit in the past, so I know it works as expected. Try running your query in the Developer Console and make sure you're getting results back.

Comment: Thank You ,i am checking my form whether it is posting the value or not